# Is there a way to style header rows only in InDesign CS6?

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables

I'm currently making a bunch of tables in InDesign and for most of these I would like to have a header row using a brand colour.

The tables currently look like this:
[image]

And I would ideally like them to look something like this:
[image]

I can so far only accomplish this using a separate rectangle shape or a separate table, which is obviously a bit limiting.

I've tried adding header rows in the table option panel:
[image]

But the options for editing this header row seems extremely limited:

[image]

Tell me, am I doomed to manually adding header rows here? Or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's `Window > Styles > Table styles` and  `Window > Styles > Cell styles`, which you should pretty much always use when working with tables in Indesign. <sup><sub>Both panels were introduced cs3</sub></sup>

Create a new table style in the `Table styles` panel and double click it to go to its options.

There you can assign cell styles to specific parts of the table. If you click the marked dropdown lists, there will be `New cell style` option so that you don't have to leave this window, incase you haven't made any cell styles yet.

[image]

Of course, by using the `Cell styles` panel, you can manually assign styles to any cells you want.

Comment: Of course, you should create the table with header and a footer if you wish to style them. If you didn't do that initially, you can select the first or last row, then right click the document and select either: `Convert to header` or `Convert to footer`.

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks @Joonas